# Why won't Egit let me push my repository to github after adding new files to a freshly cloned repo?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

Basically I'm using Eclipse with Egit on Windows. I was having issues with a file not pushing correctly so I just started a new repository since it was a small project. So I deleted the repository from github, made a new one, imported the new one through Eclipse, copied the files (without the .git folder) from the old project into the new one, committed the changes, and tried to push. But it just tells me everything is up to date without sending any files. No errors, just "up to date."

What could be the problem here?

Comment: If you do a git status from the command line what do you get?
Have you added all the new files?

Comment: Well there you go. I'm still totally new to git and assumed that the egit plugin was smart enough to handle that. I just added from the command line manually and everything went perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the command line. You can easily add new untracked files in the commit dialog. Press the button on the right showing a question mark to show untracked files. Afterwards select them for commit like you select changed files.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the Egit plugin does not add files for you automatically if you copy them into a project and try to commit changes. To fix this you need to add the files through the command line before you can sync correctly through egit, as per Alex Florescu's comment.

I fixed this by just running `git add --all` in my project directory. Luckily a simple solution!

Comment: i only had a few classes so i just created each file again and copied the code over